# Como mostrar inputs en javascript en formulario

Tags: php, javascript, html

buen día.

estoy mostrando 'N' numero de input con un select y este no funciona si esta dentro de un formulario, ya que si esta dentro de un formulario no hace nada.. tambien tengo el problema que cuando selecciono un numero por ejemplo 2 me muestra 2 input y despues selecciono el numero 3 en select me muestra 5 inputs como si los sumara.

**Codigo sin Formulario** donde si no hay formulario funciona pero suma el numero de inputs el cual lo que quiero es que solo muestre el numero de inputs que selecciono

```js
  function numerocampos()
  {

    var numero = document.getElementById("campos").value;
     
    var padre = document.getElementById("inputs");

    for(var i=1; i<=numero; i++)
    {

      //aquí agregamos el componente de tipo input
      var input = document.createElement("INPUT");

      //aquí indicamos que es un input de tipo text
      input.type = 'text';

      //y por ultimo agreamos el componente creado al padre
      padre.appendChild(input);
    }

  }
```

```html
<select name="numerocampos" id="campos" onchange="numerocampos()">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<div id="inputs"></div>
```

**Codigo con Formulario** donde si esta dentro de formulario no funciona

```js
  function numerocampos()
  {
    var numero = document.getElementById("campos").value;
    var padre = document.getElementById("inputs");


    for(var i=1; i<=numero; i++)
    {

      //aquí agregamos el componente de tipo input
      var input = document.createElement("INPUT");

      //aquí indicamos que es un input de tipo text
      input.type = 'text';

      //y por ultimo agreamos el componente creado al padre
      padre.appendChild(input);
    }

  }
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="">
<select name="numerocampos" id="campos" onchange="numerocampos()">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
</form>
    <div id="inputs"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando está dentro del formulario el nombre de la función entra en conflico con el atributo `name`, por lo cuál para el código que estoy colocando abajo le cambié el nombre de la función.

Sobre la cantidad errónea de `inputs` que te aparecen, es debido a que la primera vez que seleccionas, se agregan los elementos. Pero en las siguientes selecciones se agregarán nuevos elementos, manteniendo los que se insertaron en selecciones previas. Para corregir esto, el elemento `<div id="inputs"\>` debería estar "limpio" o sin elementos antes de la inserción. Hay varias maneras para hacerlo, en el código puse dos.

```js
function numeroCampos()
  {
    var numero = document.getElementById("campos").value;
    var padre = document.getElementById("inputs");
    while (padre.firstChild) {    padre.removeChild(padre.lastChild);  }
    //padre.innerHtml = "";

    for(var i=1; i<=numero; i++)
    {

      //aquí agregamos el componente de tipo input
      var input = document.createElement("INPUT");

      //aquí indicamos que es un input de tipo text
      input.type = 'text';

      //y por ultimo agreamos el componente creado al padre
      padre.appendChild(input);
    }

  }
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="">
<select name="numerocampos" id="campos" onchange="numeroCampos()">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
</form>
    <div id="inputs"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @eag845 ya funciono a la perfección.